# Node.js public static folder to serve js with utf-8 charset

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, utf-8, express

I´m using node.js and express to serve static JavaScript files to a single page application.
In the node.js server code I use express.static to allow public access folder

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

In the client side, I use `$.getScript` to get the JavaScript files stored in the public folder, for example:

```
$.getScript("js/init.js");
```

When I try to get some JavaScript files that have letters with accents or some UTF-8 special character I get strange characters instead of what I want.

Is there any way to set the charset when I define the public folder?

Comment: Are you sure your init.js file is saved in utf8?

Comment: or just not have the characters? :)

Answer (score 3):

An answer from [What's the simplest way to serve static files using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576644/whats-the-simplest-way-to-serve-static-files-using-node-js#14576675) gave me the hint of inserting your own middleware before static.

The code below finds `*.js` files and sets the charset to utf-8.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (/.*\.js/.test(req.path)) {
    res.charset = "utf-8";
  }
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

After doing this, look for the following response header.

```
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: This is a good answer; this actually saved me when using `superagent` to test the text of .JS files retrieved from an Express static server, as `superagent` was not returning the text of the file unless it had UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: You can also get a slightly more expressive conditional using the Node.js `path` library. 

`var path = require('path');
if (path.extname(req.path) === '.js') {
  // it's JS
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your html pages there has to be the same encoding as the encoding of your resource files (or the other way around)

Make sure you set a meta tag in the head section:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'></meta>
```