# Where to put the image file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, image, node.js, src

I have the following directory structure in Linux with just 3 files in it:

/home/nikhil/test_img/

- server.js
- page.html
- pic.jpg

This is a simple node.js hello world setup without using express or any other library

Code for server.js

```
var http = require("http"), fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var root = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
var filePath = path.join(root + '/page.html');

var port = 8889;

function onRequest(request, response) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            throw err; 
        }    
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }); 
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server has started at port " + port);
});
```

This simply creates the server which displays page.html on any request to localhost:8889

Code for page.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Page</title></head>

<body>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
<img src="pic.jpg" alt="image">
</body>

</html>
```

This is a simple webpage with Hello World heading and an image.

Now, the error is that the image does not get displayed when the page is loaded when I hit localhost:8889 on my browser. But, the image is displayed when I simply open the webpage through my browser (not via node).

I have also tried changing the src to

- "/home/nikhil/test_img/page.html"
- "file:///home/nikhil/test_img/page.html"
- "localhost:8889/page.html"
  But, none of these work

Also, I tried printing my location in javascript using `<script>alert(document.location.pathname);</script>`

The path printed was

> /

Whereas, when I ran the page directly in my browser (without node), it was

> /home/nikhil/test_img/page.html

Where do I need to put the image file for this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to serve static files using node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576644/whats-the-simplest-way-to-serve-static-files-using-node-js)

Comment: You don't separate handlers; you always send the HTML document. Head to http://localhost:8889/pic.jpg to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says that each request should serve the file that corresponds to `filePath` i.e. the  html file `page.html`. This is fine for the page request itself, but the `img` tag in your html page creates a separate request for the image `pic.jpg` which should exist in the same path as the page. But instead of serving the img file, which means your request handler would return something with header `Content-type: image/jpg`, your request handler again responds with the html page's contents and header `Content-Type:text/html`.

You need to differentiate what to serve, based on what is being requested.