# How to set default character encoding for Express.static?

Tags: node.js, express, character-encoding

I am using Express to run simple HTTP server (all real communication goes over Socket.IO). I used this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Which runs server over current directory. My problem is that the encoding header is not sent. How can I set the default charset encoding? I'd like to avoid overriding some methods just because of that.

Comment: [_**Here**_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095347/node-js-public-static-folder-to-serve-js-with-utf-8-charset) a link how to manage it, but it doesnt use the _express.static_ middleware you can define your own middleware for it.

Answer (score -5):

You should set a meta tag in head section of your html

```
<meta charset='utf-8'></meta>
```

If you need to set charset for every response, I recommend to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) plugin for this purpose. It has default charset utf-8.